# Get the href text of a link that has a certain class attribute using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I get just the text from a href in an anchor tag that matches a class.  So if I have

```
<a href="Link_I_Need.html" class="Unique_Class_Name">link text</a>
```

how can I get the string Link_I_Need.html from only the anchor tag with the class Unique_Class_Name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`.find()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) or [`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method in order to select element(s) that have a `href` attribute and a class attribute of `Unique_Class_Name`. Then iterate over the elements and access the `href` attribute value:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
anchors = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'Unique_Class_Name', 'href': True})

for anchor in anchors:
    print (anchor['href'])
```

You could alternatively use a basic CSS selector with the [`.select()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for anchor in soup.select('a.Unique_Class_Name'):
    if anchor.has_attr('href'):
        print (anchor['href'])
```

Comment: Or using css selector `soup.select('a.Unique_Class_Name')`

Comment: I was able to use this to get exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!  This is my first time using beautifulsoup so I'm trying to learn the syntax and how it all works.

Comment: Have you checked if we can simplify the last solution to `soup.select('a.Unique_Class_Name[href]')`?

Comment: @alecxe Yes, I did try using the `[href]` attribute selector before posting this, but I got the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Do I need to use a specific version or something? It seems like only simple CSS selectors are supported..

Comment: @JoshCrozier yeah, `BeautifulSoup` has a very limited support for CSS selectors, just thought it would still be able to process both the class and the attribute selectors, thanks for checking!

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="blueText" href="/info/046386294000000899/?s_bid=046386294000000899&amp;s_sid=FSP-LSR-002&amp;s_fr=V01&amp;s_ck=C01" target="_blank">川村商店</a>
```

You can get the only text like this

```
for url in url_list:
    res = requests.get('%s' % url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    for p in soup.find_all('a', class_='blueText'):
        print(p.text)
```

Comment: That one helped. Thanks